# Unable to Connect MySQL container to Tomcat Container in docker

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

**The Plan**

I want my tomcat server to be able to connect to my MySQL server both in separate containers.

**The Problem**

Tomcat cannot connect to MySQL

I used some of the details from the [wordpress tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/) about setting up a link with the mysql container and created the link to the MySQL.

Although the tomcat and mysql spin up just fine I can't seem to get tomcat to be able to connect to MySQL, the settings work on my local machine perfectly fine.

I've attempted to use `--net: "host"` as well although that does not work with Tomcat as it throws a severe error.

**Previous answers**

I [noticed on this post a load](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10772407/3746816) of possible fixes for the error although I don't believe any of these would translate to my problem as I believe this is a docker problem not a host one.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
web:
  image: tomcat:7.0
  container_name: tomcat-container
  ports:
   - "80:8080"
  hostname: docker-tomcat
  volumes:
   - /home/webapps:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps
  links:
   - db
db:
  image: mysql
  container_name: mysql-container
  environment:
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: Mysqlpassword1
   MYSQL_DATABASE: tracker
  volumes:
   - /home/mysqlDB:/var/lib/mysql
```

This is my `Context.xml from tomcat.`

```
<Context>
    <Resource
        name="jdbc/tracker" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" 
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tracker?useSSL=false"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        username="root" password="mysqladmin1"
    />
    <Resource
        name="jdbc/jenkins" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" 
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jenkins?useSSL=false"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        username="root" password="mysqladmin1"
    />
</Context>
```

The error code.

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
at databaseConnections.SQLDatabaseConnection.tableExists(SQLDatabaseConnection.java:131)
at databaseConnections.JiraSQLDatabaseConnection.<init>(JiraSQLDatabaseConnection.java:50)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you're linking db as "db", you cannot use localhost to join you database. you should "db"

```
jdbc:mysql://db:3306/tracker?useSSL=false
```

In your container, localhost design your tomcat container, not your host. MySQL container has his own network.

Futhermore, if you don't like "db" name, you can name link it with different name

For exemple:

```
 links:
   - db:container-mysql
```

In this case, inside you tomcat container, you could use

```
jdbc:mysql://container-mysql:3306/tracker?useSSL=false
```

Comment: Is it possible to do something like `- db:localhost` so that I do not need to change it from development settings to deployment settings?

Otherwise thank you very much I'll try it shortly.

Comment: I never try to use localhost. I think localhost is a keyword. You can try, may be localhost will work, but I think you should not.

Comment: In fact, I Think you should still use "my-mysql-server" in your docker and on your computer, and change on your computer to add this entry to your local dns (/etc/hosts)

Comment: Thank you your response worked. Although now I have a another problem `[Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'172.17.0.3' (using password: YES)
` even though I have granted all priv's. `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION ` Any idea why?

Comment: @Jack, did you try the - db:localhost thing? did it work for you, please

Comment: @gbenroscience I can't really remember I'm afraid. I think I just made two separate files. One for local dev and one for remote.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a container already running or run by using separate DockerFile, then you might want to consider using

```
external_links:
  -  mysql-container:db
```

Note that the name `mysql-container` is the name of your container. If you don't know the name or haven't specified one in the `docker-compose.yml` you can also find it by running

```
docker ps
```

The column with the `NAMES` is the one you'll need in the external links. The `db` after `:` is just an alias and it could be anything you want. It will be your hostname. For example if before dockerizing the database your host was `localhost` you have to now change it into `db`.

Lastly, you must also be sure to have both of the containers running in the same network. You can do that by creating a new network as:

```
docker network create --driver=bridge my-network
```

Then inside the `docker-compose.yml` of both the containers, add the following network configuration at the same indentation level as that of `service`

```
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: my-network
```