# how to access mysql docker container in spring boot docker container

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

i have 2 docker file

**1. mysql-dockerfile**

```
 FROM mysql:5.5

 EXPOSE 3306

 ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD root

 ENV MYSQL_DATABASE ToDoList
```

command used to build dockerfiles are as below

```
sudo docker build -t mysql-img  -f mysql-dockerfile .

sudo docker run -d --name mysqlcontainer -p 3030:3306 mysql-img
```

**2. java-dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

EXPOSE 9090

WORKDIR /usr/src

COPY target/*.war todoApp.war 

CMD ["java","-jar","todoApp.war"]
```

command used to build dockerfiles are as below

```
 sudo docker build -t java-img  -f java-dockerfile .
 docker run --name javacontainer -d -p 4040:9090 java-img
```

spring boot application consist jdbc url as follow

**spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3030/ToDoList**

i am not able to start project because spring boot application in docker is not able to connect mysql db which is in another container.

one solution i found is to bring two docker container in one docker network or link docker container.
can anyone please suggest good solution, modified docker run command and modified jdbc url.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to Connect MySQL container to Tomcat Container in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35510964/unable-to-connect-mysql-container-to-tomcat-container-in-docker)

Answer (score 3):

Put them into one network and use container names as hostnames:

```
docker network create foo
docker run --network=foo --name mysqlcontainer -d mysql-img
docker run --network=foo --name javacontainer -d java-img
```

Dont expose ports - they are exposed automatically between containers inside network.

To connect inside, use `mysqlcontainer:3306` and `javacontainer:9090`.

To connect from host, you will need port exposing.