# Erorr using MySQL and Spring boot app with docker

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, docker

I try to connet my spring boot app with MySQL Docker Container.
I ran :

```
docker run --name mysql-demo -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -e MYSQL_DATABASE=test -e MYSQL_USER=sa -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=password -d mysql:lat
```

and got

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                 NAMES
8d540d1824b9   mysql:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   23 minutes ago   Up 23 minutes   3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   mysql-demo
```

In my spring app I have a property file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql-demo:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

when I try to run this app or build a jar it crash with this error

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

The app working if I use mysql locally without docker

Answer (score 1):

You didn't expose the port 3306. You must do that by using -p3306:3306 otherwise you cannot access this port.

```
docker run -p3306:3306 --name mysql-demo -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -e MYSQL_DATABASE=test -e MYSQL_USER=sa -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=password -d mysql:lat
```

Comment: Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network
 address/port) is normally permitted.
I tried using other port - docker run -p 3307:3306 --name mysql-demo -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -e MYSQL_DATABASE=test -e MYSQL_USER=sa-e MYSQL_PASSWORD=password -d mysql:latest
Still not working

Comment: Then you have to stop your local Mysql or use another port like -p3307:3306

Answer (score 0):

I ran the 2 containers in the same network

more info here:
[how to access mysql docker container in spring boot docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54218824/how-to-access-mysql-docker-container-in-spring-boot-docker-container)